# Getting Error "Module not found", when I try to build my angular-6 bundle in production mode?

Tags: angular

```
**ERROR in ./webapp/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\production\node_modules\@angular\animations' 
in 'E:\production\gateway\src\main\webapp\app'**
```

I figured out that this is due to **incorrect seaching path**. It is searching module in

```
"'E:\production\node_modules\"
```

but the correct path is

```
"'E:\production\gateway\node_modules\".
```

My webpack devDependencies are

```
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.1.5",
"web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
"webpack": "3.10.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.9.5",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
"webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
"webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
```

and dependecies are:

```
"@angular/animations": "6.1.0",
"@angular/cdk": "6.4.2",
"@angular/common": "6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "6.1.0",
```

Comment: Please post your webpack-prod.config.js

Comment: I have solved the raised question by making changes in the tsconfig.json. Previous I have @angular/* path as, "../node_modules/@angular/*", now I have do the changes as:  "paths": {
            "@angular/*": [
                "./node_modules/@angular/*"
            ]